# Compile OpenCV + Gstreamer for others

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I created a project which uses OpenCV and Gstreamer (receiving udp stream), It's working perfectly fine if open with Visual Studio (Run button). But after compiling Release x64 MT and trying  I not only need to throw a whole lot of GStreamer .dll files to open my app but even after it opens successfully when It comes to opening a stream I get a warning, because of which my program is not working (Capture return false)

```
[ WARN:0] global F:\Code\opencv_4.5.1\opencv-4.5.1\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (734) cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: no element "udpsrc"
[ WARN:0] global F:\Code\opencv_4.5.1\opencv-4.5.1\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

It seems like it can't find something. My question is :

**How to compile my project so any other Windows computer could open it and find all needed files? (bonus points for hiding .dlls)**

Thanks

Comment: its not an error but warning

Comment: Thats true, but it's preventing my application from working, when I use VLC, for example, it's successfully open my stream so It's not a network problem.
And I still wonder why it's trying to search for something in the path from my main PC?

Comment: It seems like a path to “H:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin” cause that problem
If I allow my program to use PATH and it’s in there - it’s working, but when I remove it and just copy-paste files from there to my program dir I get that “warning”.
How link those files the other way so it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out, for some reason you need o move .dll files from GStreamer /bin folder to your application main directory, and in the previous folder copy GStreamer /lib folder

```
/MyFolder
   /my app
       /*.dll
       /myapp.exe
   /lib
```

*.dll-s from " \gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin "
/lib from " \gstreamer\1.0\x86_64 "

A whole lot of files, and it’s breaking my directory organization but it’s finally working - I someone found out how to fix/improve that, please let me know :wink: