# OpenCV4 GStreamer runtime error only when the location of dll changed

Tags: opencv, dll, gstreamer

### Environment, Versions

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, C++, OpenCV 4.8, GStreamer 1.22.5

### Problem

Following lists are the dlls of GStreamer linked in OpenCV 4.8(the viewer program is [this](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)). The path of the dlls are the location where the GStreamer is installed. In this case, no problem. The video I/O using GStreamer works well in OpenCV.

[image: No Problem]

However, when the location of dlls is changed like as below lists, the problem occured. (Moved all files from `C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin` to executable folder) The changed location is where the executable file(HILLAB Beam Stabilization System.exe) is located.

[image: Problem]

The assertion message from OpenCV is:

```bash
[ WARN:0@6.595] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:2196 cv::CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::close_ OpenCV | GStreamer warning: No source in GStreamer pipeline. Ignore
[ERROR:0@6.596] global cap.cpp:645 cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(GSTREAMER): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.8.0) C:\Users\woose\Downloads\opencv-4.8.0\opencv-4.8.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp:153: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ptr in function 'cv::`anonymous-namespace'::GSafePtr<struct _GstElement>::get'
```

Is it bug of OpenCV? Any advice would be appreciated.

### Building OpenCV: GStreamer library path:

[image]

### Building OpenCV: CMake configuration results:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
ocv_init_download: OpenCV source tree is not fetched as git repository. 3rdparty resources will be downloaded from github.com by default.
Detected processor: AMD64
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.7")
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.1.3, BUILD = opencv-4.8.0-libjpeg-turbo
libjpeg-turbo(SIMD): SIMD extensions disabled: could not find NASM compiler.  Performance will suffer.
Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1). OpenJPEG will be built from sources
OpenJPEG: VERSION = 2.5.0, BUILD = opencv-4.8.0-openjp2-2.5.0
OpenJPEG libraries will be built from sources: libopenjp2 (version "2.5.0")
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2021.8.0 [2021.8]
at: C:/opencv/4.8.0/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2021.8.0
at: C:/opencv/4.8.0/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
Could NOT find LAPACK (missing: LAPACK_LIBRARIES) 
    Reason given by package: LAPACK could not be found because dependency BLAS could not be found.

Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE) (found version "1.8.0_251")
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Processing WORLD modules...
    module opencv_core...
Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
    module opencv_imgproc...
    module opencv_imgcodecs...
imgcodecs: OpenEXR codec is disabled in runtime. Details: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21326
    module opencv_videoio...
    module opencv_highgui...
highgui: using builtin backend: WIN32UI
Processing WORLD modules... DONE
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.lasx.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.lasx.cpp

General configuration for OpenCV 4.8.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-09-20T03:55:22Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19045 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.22.0
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1929
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (13 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (3 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (25 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (2 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.29.30147.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO 
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core highgui imgcodecs imgproc videoio world
    Disabled:                    calib3d dnn features2d flann gapi java_bindings_generator js_bindings_generator ml objc_bindings_generator objdetect photo python_bindings_generator python_tests stitching ts video
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 python3
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.13)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.22.5)
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2021.8 [2021.8.0]
           at:                   C:/opencv/4.8.0/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2021.8.0)
              at:                C:/opencv/4.8.0/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
    Flatbuffers:                 builtin/3rdparty (23.5.9)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/Users/woose/Downloads/opencv-4.8.0/opencv-4.8.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/woose/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    Java:                        NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/opencv/4.8.0/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429213/13050727).

The dll requires the whole `lib` directory of the gstreamer, so I need to copy the `C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib` into the executable's folder too.

```bash
\Release
  MyProgram.exe
  opencv_world480.dll
  all_gstreamer_dlls.dll # copied from C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin\*
  \lib # copied from C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib
```